# Italic QComboBox button text

Tags: qt, stylesheet, qcombobox

I have a read-only QComboBox where I want the text in the "button" part (i.e. not the drop down list that can appear) to be italic. I tried using

```
combo.setStylesheet('font-style: italic')
```

but this also makes the text in the drop-down list italic. How can I force the stylesheet to not apply to the drop down list? I know I can access the drop-down part by `QComboBox::view()` but how can I then reset the stylesheet of that part?

Is there any other way to make only the text in the button part of a QComboBox italic?

Comment: Are you referring to the lineEdit()? Or is your QComboBox not editing enabled?

Comment: It does not have editing enabled.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
MyComboBox::showPopup()
{
    QStyle widget_style = style();
    setStyle(QApplication::style());
    QComboBox::showPopup();
    setStyle(widget_style);
}
```